# Learning Guitar being left-handed

Tags: guitar, learning

I'm interested in learning how to play the guitar, but can't figure out whether to start with a regular guitar or a lefty one, because I'm left-handed. I've been learning to play the piano for a little less than a year, and would really like to be able to play with a regular guitar, not having to carry mine around. Should I learn as a right-handed person or maybe play with the guitar upside down? All my experience with music learning dates to a little less than a year, but I'm familiar with a couple of theoretical concepts as well so figuring things out should be a little easier with the piano to back me up.